# Log4j message object unexpectedly rendered after source step in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2

While debugging some Java code (Log4J 2.5), I'm seeing a weird behaviour which I'm not able to reason.

In the process of rendering a Log4J log message, an object of `Log4jLogEvent` is constructed:

```
public LogEvent createEvent(String loggerName, Marker marker, String fqcn, Level level, Message data, List<Property> properties, Throwable t) {
    return new Log4jLogEvent(loggerName, marker, fqcn, level, data, properties, t);
}
```

The c'tor of `Log4jLogEvent` ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.2/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/Log4jLogEvent.java#220))
is a simple one, which assigns the given parameters into the newly constructed object fields:

```
private Log4jLogEvent(String loggerName, ... Message message, ...)
{
    this.endOfBatch = false;
    this.loggerName = loggerName;
    this.marker = marker;
    this.loggerFqcn = loggerFQCN;
    this.level = level == null?Level.OFF:level;
    this.message = message;                    // <--- issue is seen here
    ...
```

The issue is with the assignment into the `message` field.
`message` is a `ParameterizedMessage` ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta4/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.java#74)),
and has a `formattedMessage` field, which is a String.

By simply stepping over `this.message = message`, the variables/watch window shows that, all fields of `message`
were copied into `this.message`, as expected, **except** for `formattedMessage`, which was *rendered* (changed from `null` to the actually rendered string).

Screenshot before the source step (*IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1*):

[image]

Screenshot after the source step - note the value of `formattedMessage`:

[image]

Looking into the code of `ParameterizedMessage`, the only function which may perform this rendering is `formatMessage`, called 
by `getFormattedMessage()`. So my working assumption is that, `getFormattedMessage()` is somehow called.

My question:

- Is this even possible - for `getFormattedMessage()` to be called implicitly?
- Or is there some code which is being executed, but IntelliJ doesn't reveal?
- Or is there something very basic I'm missing?

When trying to "step into" this statement, it just steps over it.
I tried to place breakpoints on `getFormattedMessage()` and all other functions of `ParameterizedMessage`, 
but none was hit when doing this source step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `toString()` doing its work. The debugger shows the values based on `toString()`, and in this case `toString()` calls `getFormattedMessage()`.

So it's not the assignment doing anything, it's the debugger invoking `toString()` and doing things through that.

Comment: Thanks, that didn't come to mind! While this sounds like a plausible explanation, the `toString()` implementation of `ParameterizedMessage` does not actually call `getFormattedMessage()`. Could there be some alternative explanation? Perhaps some tailored handling by IntelliJ?

Comment: No, IntelliJ is innocent. All it's doing is showing what `toString()` returns. It seems that [toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta3/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.java#ParameterizedMessage.toString%28%29) doesn't call `getFormattedMessage()`, but it does some formatting of it's own. There's no mystery here.

Comment: I understand now that IntelliJ invokes `toString()` to display `this.message`, but I still don't understand where exactly `this.message.formattedMessage` is updated - if not by `toString()`, then by who? In the before and after screenshots, we can see the output of `toString()` next to `message` and `this.message`, and it's the same in both - that's fine, but still, the `formattedMessage` field is different.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're talking about. Could be some debugger weirdness (showing `null` for `formattedMessage` even though it's not).

Comment: @Kayman After testing with Eclipse too, it seems it's actually the other way around - showing `formattedMessage` rendered value, even though it's `null`! With Eclipse Oxygen, `formattedMessage` is null before the step, and remains null afterwards, as expected (and the first time we see the rendered message is in the appender). So this must be some kind of weird IntelliJ quirk, or "feature".

Comment: You might want to open a ticket on the JetBrains site to see what this is about. It's definitely not regular debugger functionality.

Comment: Right, I'm planning to

Comment: Log4jLogEvent.toString calls message.getFormattedMessage()

Comment: @Egor well so it does. First I looked it up and saw it being called, then I looked it up again and couldn't see it called, now I see it called again. Maybe I was looking at the wrong version.

Comment: @Egor @Kayaman right, I missed that! I was focused on `this.message = message` where stepping showed the issue. Still, I think this may be an issue for IntelliJ. While this is probably unusual, `toString()` has side effects here, so one way of preventing `formattedMessage` from being updated in the debugger is, not invoking `toString()` on null objects. Does this make sense?

Comment: Scratch that. Now I realize `toString` is called for `this` of `Log4jLogEvent`. I wonder if there's a way around that, for seeing the unaffected values as if `to String` wasn't executed.

Comment: After all, I guess `toString()` with side effects is a no-no, so maybe this is an issue for Log4J2.
Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494488/do-tostring-side-effects-get-applied-in-java-debugging

Comment: you can disable debugger toString renderer in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java